# Is a list of programming languages available?

Tags: programming-languages

Does anybody have a list of programming languages as a table (**sql**) or as **CSV**?

I'm currently writing a chess software which should allow programmers to write their own chess software and play chess games against other chess software / players. They should have the possibility to provide information about their software, such as the programming language they used. I would like to make some statistics of the most used programming languages, so I can't allow them to write the used languages as plain text as the spellings might be different (e.g. C++, c++, CPP).

edit: I want a structured list where I can easily extract the Name of the programming language. Of course, I can manually type the wikipedia-list or write a RegEx to do so. But I thought this might be available like the list of timezones.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages

Comment: Chessception. Also, you can use something like string.lower() in order to normalize your input. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages) might be a good place to start; you can get a list of the major ones there. However, be aware that you'll never get a list of *every* language, and that not all languages are created equal. Communicating between them might be tricky. Good luck!

Comment: As well as doing automatic normalising, you can look through the list and merge duplicates (and that can include having something that recognises aliases and does it automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three people so far have given you wikipedia's link. However, this is something not even wikipedia can adequately keep up with.

If you can, it might be better to just keep your own list. Provide it to the users to pick from, but allow them the option to add in a language that isn't on the list already. That way you don't clutter up your list of languages with hundreds of esoteric unused languages (that will still be incomplete 6 months from now).